# Charts.Add method causes unexpected results with FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a script to parse a data file, do some analysis on the data, and show some charts; and I ran into this quirk. I am using VBA7 in Excel 2010 (Microsoft Office Professional Plus).

It took a lot of hunting but it seems the problem occurs after the Charts.Add method is called. Assignments to a cell's FormulaR1C1 following that call do not produce the results I expect. In the code below I expect `=R[0]C[-1] - R[-1]C[-1]` in cell E3 to be translated to `=D3-D2`. Instead I get `=XFD1 - XFD1048576`.

Deleting the freshly created chart restores the expected behavior. This isn't a desirable solution.

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()

Dim x As Double
Dim ch As Chart

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'some data to work on
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Charts.Add free"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Charts.Add called"
    .Cells(1, 7).Value = "Chart.Delete called"
    For x = 2 To 10
        .Cells(x, 1).Value = Sin(x)
        .Cells(x, 4).Value = Sin(x)
        .Cells(x, 7).Value = Sin(x)
    Next x

    'Desired behavior
    .Cells(3, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1] - R[-1]C[-1]"
    .Cells(3, 2).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(10, 2))

    'after Charts.Add is called, undesired behavior
    Set ch = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add
    .Cells(3, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1] - R[-1]C[-1]"
    .Cells(3, 5).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(3, 5), .Cells(10, 5))

    'after that chart is deleted, desired behavior resumes
    ch.Delete
    .Cells(3, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1] - R[-1]C[-1]"
    .Cells(3, 8).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(3, 8), .Cells(10, 8))
End With
End Sub
```

I was able to reproduce the quirk with the above code. The AutoFill statements aren't really necessary for demonstrating the undesired behavior. But they show why I want to use relative references instead of absolute references.

I think I could get around this bug in my data parsing script by using the A1 reference style. However, using R1C1 is easier (and more readable) than translating column letters to numbers.

Another workaround would be to simply wait until the end of the data parsing & analysis loop to create the charts. But then I would have to do additional record keeping (since I would need to use information from the first loop in the second loop).

Is this just a quirk with VBA or am I misunderstanding something here? I will certainly admit I'm pretty new to R1C1, but why would a chart have anything to do with how excel translates R1C1 to A1 references? Is there some kind of "clean up" I should be doing after using Charts.Add (other than Chart.Delete!)? Or perhaps an alternative to Charts.Add?

Comment: I would say it's quite funny situation. To solve it you can add `.activate` (to activate data sheet) method in the line right after the line where you create the chart.

Comment: @KazJaw I swear I tried adding that to my data parsing script and didn't see any improvement. But now that I try it again it works! I must have gotten confused by all my extra debugging lines making things too sloppy to read. Thanks for the helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.Select` statement between `Set ch = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add` and `.Cells(3, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1] - R[-1]C[-1]"`.  When the new chart is added, it creates a new tab which is then the active sheet.  To re-activate Sheet1, you need the `.Select`

See the new code below.

```html
Option Explicit
Sub main()

Dim x As Double
Dim ch As Chart

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'some data to work on
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Charts.Add free"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Charts.Add called"
    .Cells(1, 7).Value = "Chart.Delete called"
    For x = 2 To 10
        .Cells(x, 1).Value = Sin(x)
        .Cells(x, 4).Value = Sin(x)
        .Cells(x, 7).Value = Sin(x)
    Next x

    'Desired behavior
    .Cells(3, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1] - R[-1]C[-1]"
    .Cells(3, 2).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(10, 2))

    'after Charts.Add is called, undesired behavior
    Set ch = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add
    .Select   'This statement re-activates 'Sheet1'
    .Cells(3, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1] - R[-1]C[-1]"
    .Cells(3, 5).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(3, 5), .Cells(10, 5))

    'after that chart is deleted, desired behavior resumes
    ch.Delete
    .Cells(3, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1] - R[-1]C[-1]"
    .Cells(3, 8).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(3, 8), .Cells(10, 8))
End With
End Sub
```